# Can I read in binary data with istream in c++?

Tags: c++, fread, istream

Right now I am using istream to read in data.  I have both text which I would like to read in as strings and numbers, and hashes which are read into character arrays.  Since hashes are effectively random, I am hitting snags when I try to read it back in and hit EOF (which is part of the hash).  Is there a way to accomplish this without resorting to fread.  Also, is there a to use both istream and fread some I don't have to parse the integers and strings by hand.  Finally, what is the best way to use fgets to get a string of unknown length.

Thanks,
Eric

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
string dummy;
ifstream in(fileName);
for(int i=0; i<numVals; i++)
{
    int hashLen;
    in>>hashLen;
    char cc;
    in.get(cc);//Get the space in between
    cout<<"Got first byte: "<<(int)cc<<endl;

    char * hashChars = new char[hashLen];
    in.read(hashChars, hashLen);
    for(int j =0; j <hashLen; j++)
    {
        char c = hashChars[j];
       unsigned char cc = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(c);
        cout<<"Got byte: "<<(int)c<<(int)cc<<endl;
        if(in.fail())
        {
            cout<<"Failed! "<<in.eof()<<" "<<in.bad()<<endl;
        }
    }

delete hashChars;

    getline(in,dummy);//get a dummy line
    cout<<"Dummy: "<<dummy<<" numvals: "<<numVals<<" i: "<<i<<" hashLength: "<<hashLen<<endl;
}
```

My output looks like:

1>Got first byte: 32

1>Got byte: 4 4

1>Got byte: -14 242

1>Got byte: 108 108

1>Got byte: 87 87

1>Got byte: 113 113

1>Got byte: -116 140

1>Got byte: -106 150

1>Got byte: -35 221

1>Got byte: 0 0

1>Got byte: -91 165

1>Got byte: 39 39

1>Got byte: 111 111

1>Got byte: 7 7

1>Got byte: 126 126

1>Got byte: 16 16

1>Got byte: -42 214

1>Dummy:  numvals: 35 i: 12 hashLength: 16

1>Got first byte: 32

1>Got byte: 14 14

1>Failed! 1 0

1>Got byte: -65 191

1>Failed! 1 0

1>Got byte: -107 149

1>Failed! 1 0

1>Got byte: -44 212

1>Failed! 1 0

1>Got byte: -60 196

1>Failed! 1 0

1>Got byte: -51 205

1>Failed! 1 0

1>Got byte: -51 205

1>Failed! 1 0

Comment: A sample of your data and the code you're using to read it would go a *long* way in getting answers to what is going wrong.  And regarding parsing integers and strings by hand, formatted extractors with `istream`s are the cats pajamas.

Comment: EOF cannot be part of the hash, because EOF is a concept that cannot be embedded inside of a file.  However you are reading in data, that's wrong.

Comment: Yes streams can read binary data. Streams come with functions for parsing integers and strings of varying lengths.  Do not use fgets, fread, or other c functions in C++ please.

Comment: That code doesn't match that output

Comment: The 1> was added by a different part of the code.  Also, I realize I'm missing a couple of lines.

Comment: You talk about problems your having, but your code doesn't seem to have any of those problems.  Please explain the exact problems you're encountering.  You say you want to read a string of unknown length.  How will you know how much to read?  Will you first read in the length?  Does it stop at a newline or space?

Comment: It's hitting eof().  It shouldn't be.  There is still more to read.  However, it continuously reads "205" as you can see are the last two numbers it prints out.

Comment: What I mean when I say "It shouldn't be" is that is not the end of the file.  I can open it with notepad and see that.

Comment: You read the data before enter in the for loop, why you call the in.fail inside the for loop if you are not reading data inside it.

Comment: You should have `if (in.read(...)) { ... rest of code in here ... }`.

Comment: I just put the fail check in there to print out what was happening.  I don't expect to need it because the file is a fixed format and I know the data will be there.  However, when I started to read all "205"s after a certain point, I put the check in to see what was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading binary data you generally want to open your `std::ifstream` with the flag `std::ios_base::binary`. The resulting differences are fairly small but they generally do matter.

There are a few oddities in your code you might want to fix:

- You **always** need to check after reading if the operation was successful, e.g., using `if (in.read(hashChars, hashLen)) { ... }`
- There is no need to use `reinterpret_cast<...>()` which always has implementation defined semantics. You should use `static_cast<unsigned char>(c)` instead.
- You allocate an array of characters but you release it using `delete p`. You need to use `delete[] p` instead. Using `delete p` results in undefined behavior. There isn't really any need to use `new` and `delete` at all, though, as `std::vector<char> hashChars(hashLen)` does automatic memory management.

There are a few [mutilated] questions otherwise embedded in the request above (so the questions/answers are guesses of what is being asked):

- Can you mix `std::istream::read()` and `fread()` on the same stream (I suppose this is the question): not immediately unless the stream happens to be `std::cin` which reads from the same source as `stdin`. If you want to use both `std::istream::read()` and `fread()` on the same file you'll need to wrap a `FILE*` by a suitable `std::streambuf` and initialize an `std::istream` with the corresponding object.
- How to read an arbitrary sized line with `fgets()`? You can't. The buffer to `fgets()` gets allocated before attempting to fill it and can always be filled before reaching a newline. You can use `std::getline()` to read an arbitrary long line, however. If you just want to skip the line, you can use `in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` when using `std::istream`. Off-hand I don't know if there is a similar operation for `FILE*`.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, I forgot about the binary flag, which appears to make sure that ^Z (the Windows eof character) is ignored.  Now it reads the entire file.